# Is it possible to route all communication to one port, to another network interface?

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, linux-networking

Short:
I wonder if it's possible to route (with iptables), so all communication that are directed to/from 192.168.1.10 (eth0) port 40000 are sent to tun0? (VPN)

Longer:
When I'm connecting to my VPN server,  all data is routed thru the tun0 network, except this app (that's not going anywhere) that totally refuses to understand (bad programming).
This causes the app to be headbutting the system without getting out..

Is it possible to force it by routing all data that's going to 192.168.1.10:40000 to be sent to tun0 (VPN network interface), and route all incoming data from tun0:40000 to be routed back to 192.168.1.10

Update:
This is the result of IP -4 route:

```
*0.0.0.0/1 via 10.128.0.1 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp metric 20100 
10.128.0.0/22 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.128.2.129 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.128.0.1 dev tun0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev tun0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.173 metric 100 
217.64.xxx.xx via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s3*
```

Comment: `iptables` is not used for routing, `ip route` is. If I understand your problem correctly you want all traffic going in and out `eth0` to be sent through `tun0` instead (except the tunneled packets, of course). Can you add the addresses of your interfaces (`ip -4 route`) and your routing table (`ip -4 route`) to the question?

Comment: Of course for the addresses I meant `ip -4 addr`, but I got them from the routing table.

Comment: I might add that I'm pretty new at this.. Linux..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I'm connecting to my VPN server, all data is routed thru the tun0 network, except this app, that totally refuses to understand (bad programming).

Network programming has a [layered model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), it means the author of the app just tells the system to connect to a certain IP address on a certain port, he does not have to bother about the rest, since how to reach that TCP/IP socket is up to the operating system.

You problem is caused by a bad routing configuration. Let's take a couple of lines like this:

```
1.2.3.0/29 dev tun0
1.2.0.0/22 dev tun0 via 1.2.3.4
```

The first means: if the leftmost 29 bits of the destination address are identical to those of `1.2.3.0` (i.e. from `1.2.3.0` to `1.2.3.7`) send the packet directly on `tun0`. The second line means that addresses from `1.2.0.0` to `1.2.3.255`, which are not in the `/29` line must be sent to `1.2.3.4`. The kernel knows how to find `1.2.3.4` from the first line.

Windows routing tables are almost identical (they originally took the TCP/IP stack from BSD).

Now to your situation. You have two routing entries:

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.128.0.1 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s3
```

where `default` is a shortcut for `0.0.0.0/0` (all addresses). So: if the destination address starts with `0` up to `128`, it is sent through `tun0`, otherwise it is sent through `enp0s3`.

If you want to route almost all traffic through `tun0`, first find the address of the other endpoint of the VPN tunnel (probably `ip link` can help, but you didn't say what are you using for your tunnel). Let's say it is `5.5.5.5`. `tun0` is a virtual interface, which encrypts the packets sent through it and sends them to the other endpoint through a physical interface. So we need to add a route so packets to `5.5.5.5` are sent through `enp0s3`:

```
ip route add 5.5.5.5 via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s3
```

(Edit: after reading again your routing table, this is actually already there, in the last line)

Then you can route the remaining traffic through `tun0`:

```
ip route del default
ip route add default via 10.128.0.1 dev tun0
```

Depending on the way you setup your interfaces (and tunnel), you can do those things automatically, when the interfaces goes up.

**TL;DR** Just replace `0.0.0.0/1` with `default`, wherever you put it.

Comment: not that I'm completely understanding it, but I'm getting there..(maybe)  However, in a discussion with one of the "worker" with the app, he stated: **(No, it’s not possible to run PMS with a VPN because of pulling the public IP from the router and not the default adapter.
They don’t use bind().**

Comment: No program can decide which interface to use to send packets, unless is privileged (i.e. running as the `root` user).

Comment: I c, well it's not running as root, I'll try to incorporate your solution..

Comment: Just a late update, it worked perfectly.